Retrieve month abbreviation using pandasql
I am trying to create a new column using pandasql for my requirement and need to read month of current date but this is not working for me
I have a simple dataframe created as below
import pandas as pd 
import pandasql as psql
 
df=pd.DataFrame() 
df['index_val'] = [1,2]
 
v_sql_query = '''select *, current_date as 
  date_col, strftime('%B',current_date) as 
  month_col from df;
'''

df = psql.sqldf(v_sql_query, locals())

print(df)

When I tried running this code, the month_col is created with None values.
I cannot use this transformation in the pandas dataframe directly due to some limitation in my code. I want to perform this transformation only using pandasql. Can someone please help me

pandasql loads your dataframe into an in memory SQLite database for queries.
You should remember not to conflate SQLite strftime with Python's strftime.
From the SQLite docs,

The strftime() function returns the date formatted according to the format string specified as the first argument. The format string supports the most common substitutions found in the strftime() function from the standard C library plus two new substitutions, %f and %J. The following is a complete list of valid strftime() substitutions as of version 3.46.0 (2024-05-23). Earlier versions of SQLite might not support all substitutions. If an undefined or unsupported substitution is seen, the result is NULL.

To extract the current month, use one of the supported substitutions:
v_sql_query = '''select *, current_date as 
  date_col, strftime("%m", current_date) as 
  month_col from df;
'''

